# Need to disambiguate "folders"

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

I direct your attention to the [folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folders) tag.

It's being used for questions on:

- folders on the SD card/in the filesystem (you know, what we used to call "directories" until Microsoft brainwashed us)
- folders on the home screen that can hold multiple app icons
- email folders
- file folders become albums in the Gallery app if there are image files within (and they're picked up by the media scanner)

That's a mess.

I think the fourth issue there can be ignored; I'll be removing that tag from the offending question in just a minute.

The third issue is also probably just something that needs cleanup. I mean, do we really need to have a tag for [email-folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-folders) that wouldn't just be covered by [email](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email)?

The first two issues, though, definitely require disambiguation. I would suggest [homescreen-folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homescreen-folders) for the second and either [system-folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-folders) or [file-folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-folders) for the first. I also think that, because it's unique to Android, that the [folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folders) tag should become a synonym of [homescreen-folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homescreen-folders) (after we clean up the existing questions, of course).

I'm not sold on the names; I'd be more than happy to hear alternatives. I do think [folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folders) needs to be cleaned up, though.

Comment: Completely agree with that. Names sound good to me.

Comment: I agree, but think that it should be system-folders and not file-folders.

Comment: @ZnewmaN: I'm not married to either one. That's what tag synonyms are good for.

Comment: `folders` should be unused now, but I didn't synonymize it with anything yet.

Comment: Well, as I said, I don't have particularly strong feelings about it, except that the existing tag wiki makes it related to file folders (or system folders if you prefer) and I am sure that the tag will come back in the not-too-distant future.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Al on [file-folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-folders) and [home-screen-folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-screen-folders).

I also agree with not needing a separate tag for the mail folders (the [email](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) tag should be sufficient here).

Number 4 (gallery) are in practice most likely filesystem folders (except when tags would be represented as folders). I don't think this would need a separate tag.

But I'm a bit unsure where a possible synonym "folders" should point to. If the mentioned brain-washing would not have taken place, I'd happily agree on Al's suggestion here as well; but even being a MS-abstainer I must admit: on hearing the term "folder", my first association are directories, followed by email folders, and only after that the homescreen folders -- so I'm unsure about that. One good thing about that synonym would be to save us from a tag with the same name reappearing, though :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that[folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folders) tag should become a synonym of [homescreen-folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homescreen-folders)

And while it's generally not needed to blacklist a tag - the synonym option is often sufficient - it maybe worth considering blacklisting [folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folders).